# How do I redirect the user on their first login using Drupal 6?

Tags: redirect, authentication

I know how to do this in Drupal 7:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  // Check if user never logged in.
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    // Execute code (for example redirect to user edit page).
    $_GET['destination'] = 'user/' . $account->uid . '/edit';
  }
}
```

but not in Drupal 6.

How do I port the above code from Drupal 7 to Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6, the hook is named just `hook_user`

So in your case:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user
 */
function hook_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'login') {

    // The user just logged in. Place Your code here

  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear @JaywantTopno :) Please consider voting up (or accepting as answer) posts that you find helpful. That way you generate helpful points to the authors on SE and help bring more visibility to helpful posts versus posts that are unrelevant.